# How to implement fixed row count within dynamic sections in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

What I am trying to accomplish, is to show sections based on a query (so the number of sections is not fixed), but always show only 1 row per section.

I am able to accomplish this visually by implementing `numberOfRowsInSection` as such:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

So it looks fine.  However, when I go to delete a row from the Core Data-backed store (in another Controller, for example), I always get an error like this:

"Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1114
2014-04-03 18:31:22.453 TestApplication[70450:60b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 2 from section 1 which only contains 1 rows before the update with userInfo (null)"

I'm not sure why this happens.  As I said, everything seems to load fine but there is a problem when I delete a row.  Any ideas?  I can post code as needed, but not sure where to look exactly.

Here is my delete code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Perhaps I am doing this wrong, and shouldn't try to force the use of a NSFetchedResultsController here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow these rules: http://aplus.rs/2014/one-not-weird-trick-to-save-your-sanity-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller/

Summary: in all your `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods, check if you're in the window:

```
 if (self.tableView.window == nil) {
     [self.tableView reloadData]; // Add this only in begin/end updates
     return;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It make sense because you return only 1 row.

You need to have some type of condition.

For example with a bool:

```
return isDeledted ? 0 : 1 ;
```

Don't return any after deleting, you can set this bool to true.

Comment: But, that row should always exist if the section exists.  I guess that is where my problem is.  The rows aren't really tied to the data in that sense, only the sections are.  Does that make sense?  The rows contain static content created via `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: oh ok I see what you mean, another thing try `[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath` **.row** `]];`

Comment: Hmmm.. the delete seems to happen fine, but it is something in the way I am treating the UITableView that is wrong.  I guess I just cannot bind it like this and not respect the row deletion.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that what is wrong do you still get the error

Comment: Well, adding `.row` doesn't work, because it doesn't result in a `NSIndexPath`.  I think I am trying to use these pieces in a way that was not intended.  I think maybe I should just use a `NSArray` to bind the table rather than using anything related to Core Data.  That way, when I do change the database in a different Controller, this one won't try to update.

Comment: yes if you want something dynamic you want `NSMutableArray` otherwise it would be static